# How to print array of data which is matched with another array in json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is JSON format of the API im Using

```js
{
    "details":[
        {
            "id": "001",
            "name": "john",
            "age": "19"
        },
        {
            "id": "002",
            "name": "Adam",
            "age": "18"
        },
        {
            "id": "003",
            "name": "Smith",
            "age": "19"
        }
    ],
    "students":[
        {
            "id": "001",
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "id": "003",
            "status": "Active"
        }
    ]
}
```

What i want to do is i need to compare the **id of details array** with the **id of students array** if its matched means i need to print that matched one.

My Code:

```js
var data, len, len1, id, name, age, status;

const api_url = "API URL";

async function get_data_from_api() {
    
const response = await fetch(api_url);

data = await response.json();

    len = Object.keys(data["details"]).length;
    len1 = Object.keys(data["students"]).length;

    for(let i=0; i< len; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<len1; j++){
            if(data['details'][i]['id'] == data['students'][j]['id']) { 

                id     = data['details'][j]['id'];
                name   = data['details'][i]['name'];
                age    = data['details'][i]['age'];
                status = data['details'][j]['status'];

                document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+id+"</td><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+age+"</td><td>"+status+"</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
}

setInterval(get_data_from_api, 1000);

get_data_from_api();
```

this for loop code printing my results again and again till length of my array.

**Expected Output**

001 John 19 Active

003 Smith 19 Active

**Output Which occurs**

001 John 19 Active

003 Smith 19 Active

001 John 19 Active

003 Smith 19 Active

001 John 19 Active

003 Smith 19 Active

Comment: did i conveyed my code properly if anything needed for clearance pls comment down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to compare and merge two arrays. Then get the field names

```
let details = [
    {
        "id": "001",
        "name": "john",
        "age": "19"
    },
    {
        "id": "002",
        "name": "Adam",
        "age": "18"
    },
    {
        "id": "003",
        "name": "Smith",
        "age": "19"
    }
];
let students = [
    {
        "id": "001",
        "status": "Active"
    },
    {
        "id": "003",
        "status": "Active"
    }
]


let res = [];
details.map(obj => {
    res.push({ ...obj, ...(students.find((item) => item.id === obj.id)) })
});

console.log(res)
```

output

```
res = 
[ { id: '001', name: 'john', age: '19', status: 'Active' },
  { id: '002', name: 'Adam', age: '18' },
  { id: '003', name: 'Smith', age: '19', status: 'Active' } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Any comparison like that you want to use a object/map to keep track of the frequencies

```
const data = {
  details: [
    {
      id: "001",
      name: "john",
      age: "19",
    },
    {
      id: "002",
      name: "Adam",
      age: "18",
    },
    {
      id: "003",
      name: "Smith",
      age: "19",
    },
  ],
  students: [
    {
      id: "001",
      status: "Active",
    },
    {
      id: "003",
      status: "Active",
    },
  ],
};

const counts = {};
const matches = [];
// start the count at 1 we view all the details O(n)
data.details.forEach((detail) => {
  counts[detail.id] = 1;
});

data.students.forEach((student) => {
  if (counts[student.id] === 1) {
    matches.push(student);
  }
});

console.log(matches); // [ { id: '001', status: 'Active' }, { id: '003', status: 'Active' } ]
```